# Pop up box handling

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

Facing this issue with selenium ide with Python.

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xwt_widget_form_TextButtonGroup_2"]/span[2]/span'):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xwt_widget_form_TextButtonGroup_2"]/span[2]/span').click()   
    print "Clicked"
```

[image]

The Problem is when i tried pressing `ok` button in the popped up window as attached by using `[![find_element_by _xpath][1]][1]`, then sometimes on running the script it is pressing the ok button and sometimes it is not.

I had already tried `alert box handling` and `window handler` for the `multiple window`. I had also tried different options for the `different xpaths` generated.

I am looking forward to an alternate solution to the xpath or a particular xpath value which can work everytime when I run the script.

This is my first encounter with selenium, so please excuse if this looks like basicquestion.

Comment: Share HTML for this OK button

Comment: `<input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">`

Comment: But in your code you're trying to click `span`...

Comment: @Andersson: I am not aware on what object i need to click.

Comment: I'm not sure that provided HTML sample is for target OK button. Can you update your question with HTML for the whole popup?